# the basis of the natural logarithm

Tags: reference-request, logarithms

Euler found out that Euler's number was the basis of the natural logarithm.  He started with this equation for infinitely small numbers $w$:

For $a>1$:

$$a^w=1+kw$$
$w$=infinitely small numbers

$a$=base

From $a^w=1+kw$ to this:
$${a}^{jw}={(1+kw)}^{j}$$
$${a}^{jw}={(1+kw)}^{j}=1+\frac{j}{1}kw+\frac{j(j-1)}{1*2}{k}^{2}{w}^{2}+\frac{j(j-1)(j-2)}{1*2*3}{k}^{3}{w}^{3}+...$$
Then he replaced $j$ with $\frac{z}{w}$:
$$j=\frac{z}{w}$$
$z$ is any finite number, $ω$ is an infinitely small number and $j$ is an infinitely
large number.

Then he replaced $w$ with $\frac{z}{j}$:
$${a}^{z}={a}^{jw}={(1+k*\frac{z}{j})}^{j}=1+\frac{j}{1}k*\frac{z}{j}+\frac{j(j-1)}{1*2}{k}^{2}{(\frac{z}{j})}^{2}+\frac{j(j-1)(j-2)}{1*2*3}{k}^{3}{(\frac{z}{j})}^{3}+...$$
Since $j$ is infinitely large, you will get this:
$${a}^{z}=1+\frac{kz}{1}+\frac{{k}^{2}{z}^{2}}{1*2}+\frac{{k}^{3}{z}^{3}}{1*2*3}+...$$

Then you replace $z$ and $k$ with $1$ to get the base of natural logarithm:
$${a}=1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1*2}+\frac{1}{1*2*3}+...$$
My question is, why did Euler replace $k$ and $z$ with $1$ to get the base of natural logarithm?
He had made also a series for $$\log{1+x}=\frac{1}{k}(\frac{x}{1}-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}+\frac{{x}^{3}}{3}-\frac{{x}^{4}}{4}+...)$$
You can see that here in this link from page 23 to 25.
[Here is the link](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/eulernotes99.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to really understand Euler's calculation, but here's my take on it.  Obviously, to compute $a$ for $a^z,$ you set $z=1,$ so the only question is why Euler sets $k=1.$  The equation $$a^w=1+kw$$ for infinitesimal $w$ means, in standard terminology, $$k= {da^w\over dw}|_{w=0}=\ln a$$ so if $a$ is the base of natural logarithms, $k=1.$

**EDIT**

What I mean to say is that $a^w=1+kw$ is the same as $$k={a^w-1\over w}$$ for infinitesimal $w$ and this means that $k$ is the derivative of $a^w$ (as a function of $w$) at $w=0$.  Now if $a=e,$ we must have $k=1$.  I haven't read Euler's calculation, but you say that he was determining the base for natural logarithms, and I take that to mean the number $a$ such that $\ln a = 1.$

Comment: He had made also a series for $$\log{1+x}=\frac{1}{k}(\frac{x}{1}-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}+\frac{{x}^{3}}{3}-\frac{{x}^{4}}{4}+...)$$

Comment: But I don't understand this term $$k= {da^w\over dw}|_{w=0}=\ln a$$

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you don't understand?  You know that $${da^w\over dw}= a^w\ln a$$ right?

Comment: I don't understand this: $${da^w\over dw}= a^w\ln a$$

Comment: You don't know about derivatives?

Comment: Can you explain me this, please?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but I really can't explain derivatives in this forum.  You need to look at a calculus text.  You can look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) to get started.  There may be some online learning resources that explain calculus well, but I'm not familiar with them.  Google "calculus," "differential calculus," and "derivative."

Comment: oke I will do it